# Replacing chained method call using method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

"Java 8 Lambdas: Pragmatic Functional Programming" has an example for using `peek` method in `Stream` API. This piece of code prints artist nationalities whose name starts with "The":

```
Set<Nationality> nationalities = album.getMusician()
                                 .filter(artist -> artist.getName().startsWith("The"))
                                 .map(artist -> artist.getNationality())
                                 .peek(nation -> System.out.println(nation))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to rewrite this code with method references:

```
Set<Nationality> nationalities = album.getMusician()
                                 .filter(artist -> artist.getName().startsWith("The"))
                                 .map(Artist::getNationality)
                                 .peek(System.out::println)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there any solution to rewrite `filter(artist -> artist.getName().startsWith("The"))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a separate method that takes an Artist and returns a boolean:

```
private boolean nameStartsWithThe(Artist a) {
    return a.getName().startsWith("The");
}

Set<Nationality> nationalities = album.getMusician()
                                 .filter(this::nameStartsWithThe)
```

or with a static method:

```
private static boolean nameStartsWithThe(Artist a) {
    return a.getName().startsWith("The");
}

Set<Nationality> nationalities = album.getMusician()
                                 .filter(MyClass::nameStartsWithThe)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need something that composes the two methods.  There are some methods for composing methods (`IntUnaryOperator` has `compose` and `andThen` methods that can compose two `IntUnaryOperator`s into a new `IntUnaryOperator`).  But the ones I've found all seem specialized for certain types of functional interfaces; defining `compose` methods for every possible pair of functional interface types would be too unwieldy.

I did get something to work that would compose a `Function` and a `Predicate` to get a new `Predicate`:

```
static <T,U> Predicate<T> functionPredicate(Function<T,U> func, Predicate<U> pred) {
    return obj -> pred.test(func.apply(obj));
}
```

That is, it can compose a predicate that operates on `T` from a function that takes a `T` and returns `U`, and a predicate that operates on `U`.  This would *almost* work on your example, except that `startsWith` needs another parameter.  But this does work:

```
static boolean startsWithThe(String s) {
    return s.startsWith("The");
}

Predicate<Artist> pred = functionPredicate(Artist::getName, ThisClass::startsWithThe);
```

where `ThisClass` is whatever class contains `startsWithThe`.  This works.  If you want to avoid writing a new method (like `startsWithThe`), you could probably write a "parameterized predicate" generic method so that you write something like

```
Predicate<Artist> pred = functionPredicate(Artist::getName, parameterizedPredicate(String::startsWith, "The"));
```

but I haven't tried it.

So it seems it's possible to come up with *something* that will let you use method references instead of lambdas.  I question whether it's worthwhile.  To me, a method reference is just a shorthand for certain kinds of lambdas; and unless you can do what you want with a simple method reference, I'd think using a lambda is concise and clear enough, and you don't need to add all the extra rigmarole like my `functionPredicate` method.  I've seen several questions that ask something like "How can I use a method reference for this instead of a lambda?", and I honestly don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to replace that line with a method reference.

---

Method reference works by using the fact that there is only one object being used in entire lambda expression and the compiler can infer it (reference does not matter and type can be inferred) using target typing.

So,

```
artist -> artist.getNationality()
```

is replaced with

```
Artist::getNationality
```

Here `Artist::getNationality` method matches with the target type without requiring any further information.

---

In case of `artist -> artist.getName().startsWith("The")`, there are two method calls in the lambda expression. The order, parameters are important, and have to be specified.

It looks as if the `artist` reference should be inferred, but the compiler won't know what object should the `startsWith("The")` method be called on.

Hope this helps.